# Can this be a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

A quadrilateral is a polygon with four sides and four vertices. The following figure has four sides and four vertices but sides JK and KL are in a straight line.  So, can we consider this figure as a quadrilateral? or is it a triangle? but why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygon has three sides and vertices, so it is a triangle. Think about the shape not as having two sides that are in a straight line, but as a normal triangle simply with an extra point labeled on one of the sides.

Consider that if adding an extra point changed the shape, I could make this shape any $n$-gon I want.

Comment: @H Huang Now only I got it. Thanks.